# UIButton stops working when using auto layout

Tags: ios

I have put together a simple view controller programmatically with just two buttons on it. If I go old school and set frame sizes for the layout then everything is fine. However if I use auto layout constraints for the layout then the buttons appear perfectly, but they do not respond to presses. They don't even highlight. My loadview method is below in the form that leaves the buttons not working. If the frame setting code is uncommented and the constraints adding commented out, then the buttons start to respond to presses as expected. Does anyone have any idea what is going on? I would love to translate all old hardcoded layout in my code base to be constraints based, but seem to be falling at the first hurdle.

```
- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [UIView new];
    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Landing Page";

    UIButton *buildExercisesButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    self.buildExercisesButton = buildExercisesButton;
//    buildExercisesButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 312, 164, 44);
    self.buildExercisesButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.buildExercisesButton setTitle:@"Build Exercises" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buildExercisesButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buildExercisesButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:self.buildExercisesButton];

    UIButton *organiseExercisesButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    self.organiseExercisesButton = organiseExercisesButton;
//    organiseExercisesButton.frame = CGRectMake(192, 312, 164, 44);
    self.organiseExercisesButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.organiseExercisesButton setTitle:@"Organise Exercises" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.organiseExercisesButton addTarget:self action:@selector(organiseExercisesButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:self.organiseExercisesButton];

    NSDictionary *variables = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(buildExercisesButton, organiseExercisesButton);
    NSArray *constraints =
            [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[buildExercisesButton(organiseExercisesButton)]-[organiseExercisesButton]-|"
                                                    options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom
                                                    metrics:nil
                                                      views:variables];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];

    constraints =
            [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[buildExercisesButton]-|"
                                                    options:0
                                                    metrics:nil
                                                      views:variables];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
}
```

In viewDidAppear I print out the frames of the buttons. They are giving weird values, which I don't know if it is related or not. In reality the buttons are displayed beside each other in the center of the screen.

```
buildExercisesButton: {{20, -63}, {164, 44}}
organiseExercisesButton: {{192, -63}, {164, 44}}
```

Comment: Hmm... when I copied you code, it worked fine. My logs were: build frame is: {{20, 397}, {136, 44}} organise frame is: {{164, 397}, {136, 44}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem was the second line:

```
self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

With this line the view wasn't full screen, starting at the top left as expected, but started somewhere near the center. Therefore though the buttons appeared to be near the center of the screen they were actually outside of the containing view. When I removed this line everything started to work.

I guess I have discovered a gotcha for `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`. Though you have to turn it off to use constraints, that is only on the exact views that are using constraints, not for the containing view unless it too is using constraints. In this case I turned off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on the containing view, but should not have as it had no constraints for it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define constraints for the view that you are adding buttons or set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property to `YES`.

Comment: Thanks Raphael, that was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing purely Storyboard for autolayout, try increasing **Vertical** Content Hugging Priority and **Vertical** Compression Resistance Priority:

[image]

Comment: Why? What does that do?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `UIButton` frames are off the screen. The touch events depend on hitting those not the images of the buttons so that's why they're not responding.

Why are you using the auto layout instead of setting the frames?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I've written a full explanation as another answer. The reason I'm using auto layout is that I believe it is the future. Hard coded layout was OK when there were only a small number of potential screen size and dimension, but not now with the wide range of devices, plus iOS 7 and localization in the mix. Most of my views are put together programmatically so Interface Builder isn't much use either. So I'm putting in the effort to getting over the learning curve of using auto layout in code.

Answer (score 1):

I run into same problem. In my case:

```
self.view
 \- ...
  \_self.wrapper
       \_self.button
```

The code not works:

```
NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"padding":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:kGridPadding]};

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[head]-padding-[wrapper]-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
```

The reason is the height of 'wrapper' is 0, although the button is still visiable. So it can be fixed by giving enough width and height like this:

```
NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"padding":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:kGridPadding],
                          @"screenHeight":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.view.bounds.size.height]};

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[head]-padding-[wrapper(screenHeight)]-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
```

--> a better way is make the height of wrapper increase automatically, but I don't know how to do that now?

Comment: If you use the view debugger, you'll see the wrapper that Nianliang is talking about.  For me it was the superview of the view that held the button that was not responding to taps.  It had a height of 0.  To fix this I simply added a height constraint to the container view of the button.